# CIFilter (CIStripesGenerator) with SKTexture?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, cifilter, sktexture

I am trying to get a strips generated using CIFilter, then create a SKTexture from it. 
Here is my code.

```
      CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIStripesGenerator"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
    [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];

   //updated the code, whith this line   
   //stil the same problem
    CIImage *croppedImage = [filter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    SKTexture *lightTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:croppedImage]];

    SKSpriteNode *light = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:lightTexture size:self.size];
```

However, i receive a run time error at the last line, any help would be appreciated, except for (lldb), the compiler does not give any more explanation.

UPDATE:
Thanks to *rickster* for guiding me towards the solution

```
-(UIImage*) generateImage {
// 1
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIStripesGenerator"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
[filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
// 2
CGImageRef cgimg =
[context createCGImage:filter.outputImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
// 3
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
// 4
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return newImage;
 }
```

Then, i can create texture from the image:

```
    SKTexture *stripesTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[self generateImage]];

    SKSpriteNode *stripes = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:stripesTexture];
    stripes.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild: stripes];
```

Comment: (lldb) is the prompt of the LLDB debugger where you can enter commands to analyze the current state of the program. This is always visible when execution halts. There is more info in the log, check the lines above (lldb) and post them here. Also: add an exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I added the break point and still there is no description of the error. here is a screen shot of what is exactly happening. https://31.media.tumblr.com/5ae4520f0e17e7af6dca19c9c91d422d/tumblr_n2ui44d03z1s1nlcso1_500.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You don't have a Core Image context for rendering your image. Create one with:

   ```
   CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
   ```

   This probably won't provide real-time rendering performance. But it looks like you just want one-time generation of a static texture, so that's okay.
2. Most of the generator filters produce images of infinite extent. You need to either add a crop filter to the filter chain, or render your image using a method that lets you specify what rect of the image you want, like [`createCGImage:fromRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIContext/createCGImage%3afromRect%3a). Then make an `SKTexture` from the resulting `CGImageRef`.

Comment: I cropped the pattern as you explained, but i am not sure where to add the context.